# Difficulty configuring OAuth2 for Youtube Analytics API:

Tags: python-2.7, youtube, google-analytics

I'm trying to use the Youtube Analytics API via python.  I downloaded the sample python code from the Google developers website.  Here is the link:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/code_samples/python

Whenever I run it, my browser opens up a page with the following error message:

```
**Error: redirect_uri_mismatch The redirect URI in the request: [http://localhost:8080/] did not match a registered redirect URI**
```

My application on the Google Cloud Console is set up with the following redirect uri and javascript origins:

```
**Redirect URIs     
[http://localhost:8080/oauth2callback]
Javascript Origins  
[http://localhost:8080]**
```

The contents of my client_secrets.json file, which I pass to the program in line 24, looks as follows:

```
{"web":{"auth_uri":"[https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2]/auth","client_secret":"KNLERUsUrOsOiJTzyaSWN2JG","token_uri":"[https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token]","client_email":"409435120404-k62menuelac66nbl9ic82uqakbd4nhrh@developer.gserviceaccount.com","redirect_uris":["[http://localhost:8080/oauth2callback]"],"client_x509_cert_url":"[https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/409435120404-k62menuelac66nbl9ic82uqakbd4nhrh@developer.gserviceaccount.com]","client_id":"409435120404-k62menuelac66nbl9ic82uqakbd4nhrh.apps.googleusercontent.com","auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"[https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs]","javascript_origins":["[http://localhost:8080]"]}}
```

I'm running Ubuntu 13.10.  Any help resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated, as I'm at a loss for why it's occurring.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect _uris needs to be the same as what you have it set to in the apps project in developer console.

Comment: DalmTo, thanks for the reply; however, I have already set the redirect_uris to be the same as what I provide for authorization.  You can see that the addresses in my json file match.  In fact, that JSON file was produced by the google cloud console based on the redirect_uris I set.